# When does the Mayer-Vietoris sequence hold for affine algebraic varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $U$ and $V$ be affine algebraic varieties in $\mathbb{R}^k$ or $\mathbb{C}^k$. When is the Mayer-Vietoris sequence exact for $U \cup V$ and $U \cap V$? Intuitively, it feels as though the intersection may be "nice" enough so that $U$ and $V$ may be thickened into open sets in a way that will not change the homology of $U \cup V$ and $U \cap V$. Are there any references that one could suggest?

Comment: Just to make sure, you're asking about the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for singular homology, viewing everything in sight with the Euclidean topology, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools from semi-algebraic and subanalytic geometry can help us solve this problem. We may obtain a locally finite triangulation of $U\cup V$ which has as sub-triangulations $U$, $V$, and $U\cap V$. Combining this with Mayer-Vietoris for simplicial complexes and simplicial homology plus the equivalence between simplicial homology and singular homology of the geometric realization, we obtain the required result.

**Theorem** (Hironaka, *Triangulations of Algebraic Sets* in *Algebraic Geometry, Arcata 1974* p.180): Given a locally finite system of subanalytic sets $\{X_\alpha\}$ in $\Bbb R^n$, there exists a simplicial decomposition $\Bbb R^n=\bigcup_a \Delta_a$ and a subanalytic automorphism $\kappa$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that

1. each $X_\alpha$ is a locally finite union of some of the $\kappa(\Delta_a)$ and
2. $\kappa(\Delta_a)$ is a locally closed smooth real-analytic submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\kappa$ induces a real-analytic isomorphism $\Delta_a\stackrel{\sim}{\to}\kappa(\Delta_a)$ for every $a$.

This accomplishes our first goal: viewing complex varieties in $\Bbb C^m$ as real varieties in $\Bbb R^{2m}$ if necessary, we may take $\{U\cup V,U,V,U\cap V\}$ as our family to obtain a simultaneous triangulation of $U\cup V$, $U$, $V$, and $U\cap V$.

Next, we prove Mayer-Vietoris for simplicial complexes and simplicial homology. I'm sure this is written down somewhere you can reference, but I don't remember off the top of my head and a quick glance through the reference books I have at my desk didn't find it. (Plus the proof is short!)

**Theorem**. Let $K,L,M,N$ be simplicial complexes with $K=M\cup N$ and  $L=M\cap N$. Then Mayer-Vietoris holds in simplicial homology, that is, there's a long exact sequence $$\cdots\to H_n^\Delta(L)\to H_n^\Delta(M)\oplus H_n^\Delta(N)\to H_n^\Delta(K) \to \cdots$$

*Proof*. Consider the short exact sequence of complexes $$0\to C_n(L)\to C_n(M)\oplus C_n(N)\to C_n(K)\to 0$$ where the first map is the map $x\mapsto (x,x)$ and the second map is $(x,y)\mapsto (x-y)$. Apply the snake lemma to obtain the long exact sequence. $\blacksquare$

Finally, we use the fact that simplicial homology of a simplicial set is the same as the singular homology of the geometric realization: this is theorem 2.27 in Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and is also covered [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945127/homology-of-simplicial-set-vs-homology-of-its-geometric-realization).

The combination of these results shows that Mayer-Vietoris always holds for singular homology of the analytic topology on affine algebraic varieties.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the essence of the argument is that $U \cup V$, $U$, $V$, and $U \cap V$ may be simultaneously triangulated, and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence always holds for simplicial complexes, correct? The inclusion-exclusion principle for the Euler characteristic also always holds for simplicial complexes, correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$