# Cohomology of union of two closed subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have smooth algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$. Let $D_1, D_2$ be two codimension $1$ smooth subvarieties, such that the intersection $D_1\cap D_2$ is also smooth.

How to compute the cohomology (singular, with rational coefficients) of $D_1\cup D_2$ if we know cohomology of $D_1, D_2, D_1\cap D_2$?

I want some exact sequence connecting $H^*(D_1\cap D_2),H^*(D_1), H^*(D_2)$ and $H^*(D_1\cup D_2)$.

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: The assumptions really make no sense unless you have a disjoint union. Also, what kind of cohomology are you interested in? The context seems to be one of algebraic varieties.

Comment: Yes, it was misprint, I've changed the question.

Comment: It is not clear, how Mayer-Vietoris can help here.

Comment: I changed the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I proved that Mayer-Vietoris holds for affine varieties over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269846/when-does-the-mayer-vietoris-sequence-hold-for-affine-algebraic-varieties/4276968#4276968). This should be most of the way towards resolving your question. Do you need a non-affine version?

Comment: Brilliant! It seems that the fact that varieties are affine is not important, just apply standard Mayer-Vietoris and 5 lemma? Do you agree?